# Problema al pasar una imagen a un JasperReport

Tags: java

Estoy intentando enviar una imagen como parametro a un jasperRepor, pero cuando voy a generar el reporte me dice que el parametro es null.

```
public void generarReporte(String ruta) throws JRException {

    try {

        //   File reportFile = new File("");
        HashMap<String, Object> parametro = new HashMap<>();
        InputStream io = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("IME/" + ruta);

        parametro.put("logo", io);
        System.out.println(ruta);

        System.out.println(parametro.toString());
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(new File("src\\aplicacionmipe\\report1.jasper"));

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametro);
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        view.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException ex) {

        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Agrega mas detalles a la pregunta, como cual es el error, donde tienes guardada la imagen, si tienes declarado el parámetro en el reporte? etc etc...

Comment: En el propio informe , le pasaste la imagen como una variable de tipo java.awt.Image ?